# Printing a SSRS directly to printer, from a WCF Service?

Tags: reporting-services

I want to know if the following is possible, and if so, how to do it:

Let’s say I have a WCF service, which runs on a server with several Printers available. I want the WCF service to be able to ask a SQL Server Reporting Service to produce a particular report, and I want the report sent to one of my server’s printers.

Anyone know how to do this? Remember, the printers are not on the SSRS server – they’re on the server which hosts my WCF service.

Comment: Of course, as soon as I posted this, I found the answer. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bryanke/archive/2004/02/11/71491.aspx.

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution. You could summarize the post in an answer to your own question, and accept that as the solution? This will help future visitors to this question.